# eclipse's plugin or vim's plugin similar like ctrl+p and type @ to find function/method list in sublime

Tags: eclipse, vim, sublimetext2

eclipse is good at autocompletion when static  typing , when is **dynamic typing** ,eclipse failed to autocompletion ; in **sublime**  ctrl+p ,type @ and type 'method name'to find function/method list , It is a wonderful way to find the right method  while coding dynamic typing language ;

the key point is :
the operation in sublime text 2 is very convenient ,all key type is in one input box ; never need to chage active  file tab; we can focus on  the active code file tab ;

is there any plugin in eclipse or vim which can search method of any file conveniently    ?

Comment: You can find 'outline' in the eclipse.

Comment: outline can just see the active file methods , I need a more convenient plugin

Answer (score 5):

In ST2, this feature is used to quickly jump to a method anywhere in your project.

In Eclipse, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> can be used to jump quickly to a "resource" (file) and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is for jumping to a type (not method). <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> opens a very useful and quick outline of the current file. It doesn't work project-wide.

I'm not aware of something that works exactly like ST2's feature. Did you search the marketplace?

In Vim, FuzzyFinder, Command-T and CtrlP all allow you to navigate through your project using fuzzy matching. They can be setup to use your `tags` file. AFAIK, there's no plugin that provides exactly what ST2 provides.

From your question I'm not sure you use it as intended: it sounds like you use it to show a list of methods in some file in your project in order to use the right method in your code. This sounds a lot like you'd benefit from *autocompletion* to me.

Being an IDE, Eclipse shines on that front: its "code assist" window will show you where the suggestion is defined as well as its type.

Vim's "omnicompletion" is quite limited compared to an IDE but, depending on your language and using some third party scripts, it can be made quite powerful.

Comment: eclipse is good at autocompletion when static typing , but when is dynamic typing ,eclipse failed to autocompletion in OO language like python ;

Comment: fox python example : class SpyDialog(PyQt4.QtGui.QDialog, Ui_SpyDialog) def setupUi(self, SpyDialog): SpyDialog.setObjectName("SpyDialog") ----------------eclipse can autocomplete the method setObjectName  ; so if oneplugin can easily search or autocomplete all method will be very convenient

Comment: sorry maybe I donot Points out key points ; the operation in sublime text2 is very convenient ,all key type is in one input box ; never need to chage active file tab; we can focus on the active code file tab ;